# .NET URL with categories

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes, seo

I have some problems managing good looking URL for my site.

I have 3 `models`: `Town`, `Restaurant`, `Food`.

`TownController` is using `TownService` and `Index` shows all Towns (other methods are `Edit`, `Create`, `Delete`)

Similar is with `RestaurantController` - using `RestaurantService` and `Index` shows all `Restaurants` in chosen `Town`)

`FoodController` - using `FoodService` and `Index` shows all `Foods` in chosen `Restaurant`

URLs:

`/Town` - shows all `towns`

`/Restaurant/Index/1` - shows all `restaurants` in `Town` with `ID = 1`

`/Food/Index/1` - shows all `foods` in `Restaurant` with `ID = 1`

Only `/Town` is fine URL, rest are not good. Second should be more like `/Town/1`  but since RestaurantController is showing all `restaurants` in `Town` it must be written `/Restaurant/Index/1.`

Is there way to change that construction?
Also note that client insists on not using custom routes/attribute routing.

Best SEO at end would be `/Town/TownName/RestaurantID` (or even `restaurantName`) but thats not that important if you could help me with previous request.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify and add some custom routes to RouteConfig.cs in your App_Start folder.  You should have the following default route in the RegisterRoutes method

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

This route means that if you pass it nothing for the controller, the action or the id it will go to /Home/Index/, if you pass it a controller it will got to /Town/Index.  If you register the following route **BEFORE the default route** (they get tried in order, so the default route should always be last)

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Restaurant",
            url: "Town/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

this will capture any url that has '/Town/' and an integer while still letting '/Town/' by itself go to the Town controller.